# performance difference of callback and partial postback

Tags: asp.net, .net

i have read many articles regarding callback and partial postback. i have found the details of the difference between these two in the following link.

[What's the difference between a Callback and a Partial Postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016424/whats-the-difference-between-a-callback-and-a-partial-postback)

But i dont know the performance difference between callback and partial callback using ajax. Can anyone help me finding the difference?

thanks....