# what is the difference between partial postback and entire page posting in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

What do we mean by Partial post back in a page and complete page posting

1. What are the events that are Fired when a page is being Post backed
2. What are the events that are fired when a page is being Partially Post backed

What are the events that are fired when a page is being Partially Post backed.

My question is when I am trying to call a JavaScript function from code behind .

When i use

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"Call my function","MyFunction()",true);
```

it is not working where as 
when i use

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock
```

it is working for sure

Comment: Duplicate? [What's the difference between a Callback and a Partial Postback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016424/whats-the-difference-between-a-callback-and-a-partial-postback)

Comment: I believe the answer to both your questions is the same.  All events. This is the gotcha with update panels, although they look tame enough, they post the same payload as a normal (non-ajax) postback.

Comment: but here, when i raise an event in a update panel the above mentioned was not working

Comment: Does the line get hit in the code behind when debugging? One other thing to try is passing the current `Page` to `RegisterStartupScript` instead of `this.GetType()`.

Comment: @PhilCooper it worked when i use pageregisterstartupScript in the place of this.getType(). thanks